# How to read JavaScript output text in a Java Program

Tags: java, javascript, html

Hi i am trying to read forbes.com 's thought of the day in my Java program. But in the view source of the webpage i am not getting the output rendered on the html page. Any clues as to how to read the rendered output?

Heres the source code of website where i am reading the thoughts from.

```
<head>
    <script src="http://images.forbes.com/scripts/dart_forbes.js"></script>
    <script src="http://images.forbes.com/welcome/desktop/welcome_js.js?v=1.5"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        forbes_dart.ad('thoughtx', '600x100');
    </script>
</body>
```

I have minimised and removed all clutter and kept it as basic as possible.

Heres the view source of the site

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="./js/dart_forbes.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/welcome_js.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            forbes_dart.ad('thoughtx', '600x100');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my Java program

```
public class extractor {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        extractor t = new extractor();
        t.connect();
    }

    public void connect() throws Exception {
        URL obj = new URL("http://localhost:8080/q2p/thought.html");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        System.out.println(response.toString());
    }

}
```

Here's the program output

```
<html>    <head>        <script src="./js/dart_forbes.js"></script>        <script src="./js/welcome_js.js"></script>    </head>    <body>        <script language="JavaScript">            forbes_dart.ad('thoughtx', '600x100');        </script>    </body></html>
```

[SOLUTION]

Well after some help from meister_reineke heres the java code which works :) and solves the problem.

```
public class extractor {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        extractor t = new extractor();
        t.connect();
    }

    public void connect() throws Exception {
        URL obj = new URL("http://localhost:8080/q2p/thought.html");

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        HtmlPage myPage = ((HtmlPage) webClient.getPage(obj));

        System.out.println(myPage.asText());
        webClient.closeAllWindows();
    }

}
```

The output for the above code is

```
Patience strengthens the spirit, sweetens the temper, stifles anger, extinguishes envy, subdues pride, bridles the tongue.
Share
Facebook Twitter LinkedIn Google
George Horne
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you might find the answers:

[Getting Final HTML with Javascript rendered Java as String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872382/getting-final-html-with-javascript-rendered-java-as-string)

this looks a bit similiar to your question, maybe HtmlUnit can help you as well.

Comment: trying this out will let u know. Thanks :)